# Открытие в браузере HTML файла, редактируемого в Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text

Народ, может, кто знает, как запустить html файл из Sublime Text? В NotePad++ это можно выполнить шорткатом <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Comment: Я вообще не знаю, как можно запустить html. Эти файлы неисполняемые.

Comment: ну имеется как запустить браузер) - назначить приложение на выполнение

Answer (score 12):

А насколько мне известно Sublime для того и создан что бы добавлять нужный для себя функционал ;)

Все достасточно просто и немного зависит от вашей ОС

Для начала создадим новую систему сборки

```
Tools -> Build System -> New Build System...
```

в открывшемся нужно написать:

Для Mac OS

```
{
"cmd": ["open", "-a", "Google Chrome", "$file"]
}
```

Для Linux

```
{
"cmd": ["google-chrome", "$file"]
}
```

Для Windows (у меня 8.1 но должно работать почти на всех)

```
{
"cmd": ["Путь до браузера", "$file"]
}
У меня это "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
```

При этом двойной слеш нужен для экранирования

Собственно все, сохраняем файл как **Chrome.sublime-build**

**Закрываем и открываем снова SublimeText**

Заходим в

```
Tools -> Build System
```

Выбираем **Chrome** и запускать открытые файлы в нем можно нажатием **Ctrl+B**

Comment: С Вашим кодом у меня открывается Google, но не документ, в котором работаю. Работает вот такой: `{
    "shell_cmd": "\"D:/Pale Moon/palemoon.exe\" \"$file\""
}` .

Answer (score 4):

### Второй вариант

Использование Build System — функции, позволяющей открывать редактируемые в Sublime Text файлы через другие программы.

Лично у меня не заработал вариант, [предложенный ув-мым Виктором](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/416354/199934). Открылся Chrome, но не редактируемый документ. В консоли вывелось следующее:

> ```
> [3380:2968:0423/114832:ERROR:connection.cc(1934)] Cookie sqlite error 
> 1, errno 0: no such column: firstpartyonly, sql: SELECT creation_utc,
> host_key,  name, value, encrypted_value, path, expires_utc, secure,
> httponly, > firstpartyonly, last_access_utc, has_expires, persistent,
> priority FROM cookies WHERE host_key = ? AND persistent = 1
> [Finished in 13.5s]
> ```

В моём браузере [**Pale Moon Portable**](http://kristinita.ru/Life-hacks/Default-portable-browser-Windows-10) на Windows 10 файлы открываются, когда в файле «билда» с расширением `sublime-build` прямые и обратные слэши скомбинированы следующим образом:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "\"E:/Pale Moon/Palemoon-Portable.exe\" \"$file\"",
    "selector": "text.html.basic, text.xml"
}
```

Для Chrome:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "\"C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/Chrome.exe\" \"$file\"",
    "selector": "text.html.basic, text.xml"
}
```

`$file` — [**системная переменная**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html#build-system-variables), означающая открытый на данную минуту файл.

Также в сравнении с ответом Виктора я добавил новый параметр `selector`. При значении `"text.html.basic, text.xml"` когда у нас включено автоматическое переключение между Build System: (`Tools` → `Build System` → `Automatic`), в браузере при вызове Build будут открываться только XML и HTML-файлы (а также HTM, XHTML). Значения параметра — начальная часть «областей видимости»: открываем пустой файл → `View` → `Syntax` → выбираем требуемый синтаксис → получаем scope в нашем пустом файле — как это сделать, подробно расписано [**здесь**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516668/199934), — вставляем нашу область видимости напротив `selector`. В HTML, HTM, и XHTML область видимости — `text.html.basic`, в XML, соответственно, `text.xml`. Перечисление, как видно на примере, ведётся через запятую.

Да, и чтобы не нажимать каждый раз <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd>, имеются [дополнительные инструменты быстрого предпросмотра](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12829369/5951529), однако их обзор выходит за пределы поставленного вопроса.

Answer (score 4):

### Первый вариант

Для меня наиболее предпочтительный. [**SublimeServer**](https://github.com/learning/SublimeServer) — HTTP-сервер, реализованный как плагин для Sublime Text. С его использованием может отпасть нужда в Open Server, WAMP Server, Денвере, Mongoose или их альтернативах. Примеры преимуществ использования SublimeServer в сравнении с обычным открытием HTML-файла через Build System:

- Корректное отображение сторонних виджетов,
- Доступность проверки настроек файла `.htaccess`,
- Возможность проверки, как выглядит веб-страница на разных экранах, сервисом [**Screenfly**](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/),
- Размеры шрифтов совпадают с теми, которые будут видеть на сайте, а не меньшие,
- Корректная [**вставка кода с привязкой видео ко времени**](http://12starsmedia.com/blog/embed-youtube-video-specific-start-time), полученного на видеохостингах.

Устанавливаем его как и все другие плагины через Package Control → <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `SublimeServer: Start SublimeServer`. Автоматически запускать SublimeServer вместе с Sublime Text у меня [**не выходит**](https://github.com/learning/SublimeServer/issues/33). В файле, где работаем, кликаем куда-нибудь правой кнопкой мыши, и в контекстном меню выбираем `View in SublimeServer`. Можно задать хоткей: `Preferences` → `Key Bindings - User` → в открывшийся файл `Default(Ваша операционная система).sublime-keymap` вставляем `{ "keys": ["alt+home"], "command": "sublimeserver_browser" }`, где `alt+home` → выбранное вами сочетание горячих клавиш. В файле используется синтаксис JSON, следите за правильной расстановкой {фигурных}, [квадратных] скобок и запятых. Корректный пример файла `sublime-keymap`:

```json
[
    // Открыть PowerShell
    { "keys": ["alt+shift+t"], "command": "open_terminal" },
    // Открыть страницу на сервере
    { "keys": ["alt+home"], "command": "sublimeserver_browser" },
    // Emmet вверх на 1 цифры CSS
    {
        "keys": [
            "ctrl+keypad_plus"
        ],
        "args": {
            "action": "increment_number_by_1"
        },
        "command": "run_emmet_action",
        "context": [
            {
                "key": "emmet_action_enabled.increment_number_by_1"
            }
        ]
    },
]
```

Answer (score 3):

### Третий вариант

Файлы запускаются и из сайдбара, если установлен плагин [**Sidebar Enhacements**](https://github.com/titoBouzout/SideBarEnhancements). 
Кликаем правой кнопкой мыши по имени файла в сайдбаре → `Open Run` → файл откроется в сопоставленной ему программе, для HTML это обычно браузер по умолчанию.

Если желаете открыть файл в другом браузере, требуется произвести настройки: кликаем правой кнопкой мыши по имени файла в сайдбаре → `Open With` → `Edit Applications...` → в открывшийся файл вставляем код и сохраняем его:

```
{
    "caption": "Firefox Portable",
    "id": "side-bar-files-open-with-firefoxportable",

    "command": "side_bar_files_open_with",
    "args": {
                        "paths": [],
                        "application": "E:\\Firefox\\FirefoxPortable.exe", // WINNT
                        "extensions":"html|htm", //open all even folders
                        "args":[]
                    },
    "open_automatically" : false // will close the view/tab and launch the application
},
```

Где

- `"caption": "Firefox Portable"` — отображаемое имя Вашего браузера. Можно задать любое, какое удобно.
- `"id": "side-bar-files-open-with-firefoxportable"` — необходимо написать `side-bar-files-open-with-`, а дальше задаёте имя по собственному усмотрению.
- `"E:\\Firefox\\FirefoxPortable.exe"` — путь к исполняемому файлу браузера. Проще указывать абсолютный, нежели относительный. Слэши обратные и дублируются.
- `"extensions":"html|htm"` — в контекстном меню после клика правой кнопкой мыши по имени файла пункт `Firefox Portable` будет показываться только, если файл имеет расширение `html` или `htm`, расширения отделяются друг от друга через [**пайп**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0). Параметр `extensions` может принимать и другие значения:

  - `"extensions": ""` — пункт `Firefox Portable` будет показываться в контекстном меню, если мы в сайдбаре кликнем правой кнопкой мыши по файлу с любым расширением или папке.
  - `"extensions" :". *"` — пункт `Firefox Portable` будет показываться в контекстном меню, когда мы в сайдбаре кликнем правой кнопкой мыши по файлу с любым расширением, но не папке.

Кликаем в сайдбаре правой кнопкой мыши по файлу с расширением `html` или `htm` → `Open With` → `Firefox Portable` → файл откроется в портативной версии Firefox.

[image: Firefox Portable]

Answer (score 1):

### Четвёртый вариант

В последнее время для создания команд я пользуюсь фреймворком [**Suricate**](https://github.com/nsubiron/SublimeSuricate). Многофункциональный, одной из его возможностей является удобная работа с командами.

---

---

### Обоснование

Положим, мы создали [**build system для открытия текущего файла в определённом браузере**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516239/199934) и хотим запускать команду горячими клавишами, из контекстного меню, Menu Bar и command palette. Итого потребуется правка четырёх файлов: `sublime-keymap`, `Context.sublime-menu`, `Main.sublime-menu` и `sublime-commands`; а включая файл `sublime-build` нашей Build System — 5. Причём в файлах мы вынуждены писать один и тот же текст; и так для настройки каждой новой команды, которых может быть множество.

В Suricate:

1. Правится всего один файл с расширением `suricate-profile`, а не 5;
2. В этот один файл можно поместить все настройки запуска команд как плагинов, так и по умолчанию;
3. Гораздо меньше лишней писанины, ничего не надо повторять.

---

---

### Результат

#### Command palette

[image: Command palette]

#### Menu Bar

[image: Menu Bar]

#### Контекстное меню

[image: Контекстное меню]

#### Запуск шорткатом

[image: Запуск шорткатом]

---

---

### Настройка запуска файла

Устанавливаем Suricate через Package Control → `Preferences` → `Package Settings` → `Suricate` → `Default Profile — User` → в открывшийся файл вставляем следующий код:

```json
{
  "user_commands":
  {
    // Запустить Firefox
    "sasha-firefox": {
        "call": "Suricate.lib.process.spawn",
        "args": {
            "cmd": ["E:\\Firefox\\FirefoxPortable.exe", "$file"]
        },
        "caption": "Sasha Firefox",
        "group": "main.preferences",
        "keys": ["<c>+super+keypad6"],
        "context_menu": true
    },
  }
}
```

Сохраняем файл — должно работать, как на скриншотах и скринкасте выше. Не путайтесь в [**JSON-синтаксисе**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/238934/199934), следите за правильной расстановкой кавычек, скобок и запятых.

#### Параметры и значения

- `sasha-firefox` — идентификатор команды. Можете писать что угодно, лишь бы не совпадало с идентификаторами других команд.
- `call` — вызов. В примере:

  - `Suricate.lib.process.spawn` вызывается функция `spawn()` модуля Python `Suricate.lib.process`. Это аналогично запуску Build System в Sublime Text.
- `args` — аргументы команды. Синтаксис аналогичен [**используемому в Build System**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516239/199934). В примере:

  - `E:\\Firefox\\FirefoxPortable.exe` — путь к исполняемому файлу браузера. Указываете свой.
  - `$file` — [**системная переменная**](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/build_systems/configuration.html#build-system-variables) для Build System, означает, что сторонней программой, в данном случае Firefox, запустится открытый в данный момент файл.
- `caption` — текст, нажав на который в command palette, Menu Bar и контекстном меню, запускается команда.
- `group` — откуда будет запускаться команда из меню. В примере это `Preferences` → `Package Settings` → `Suricate`.
- `keys` — шорткат.

  - `<c>` — <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> для Windows и Linux и <kbd>Cmd</kbd> для MacOS.
- `context_menu` — добавлять или нет команду в контекстное меню.

---

---

### SublimeServer и Suricate

По причинам, изложенным в [**данном ответе**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/549406/199934), использование SublimeServer выглядит предпочтительнее в сравнении с открытием файла через `file:///`. Добавляем в тот же файл `Default.suricate-profile`, куда заносили пример для Firefox, следующий код:

```json
// Запустить SublimeServer
"sasha-sublimeserver": {
    "caption": "SublimeServer: View into SublimeServer",
    "keys": ["<c>+super+insert"],
    "call": "sublime.sublimeserver_browser",
},
```

Вот так я запускаю файлы в браузере. Запуск из Menu Bar и контекстного меню в примере я опустил, поскольку не пользуюсь этим.

#### Значения параметра

Синтаксис значения `call` для дефолтных команд и команд плагинов в Suricate следующий: `sublime.$команда`. Регистр имеет значение, `Sublime.sublimeserver_browser` не будет работать, как и `suricate.lib.process.spawn` в примере выше.

---

---

### Дополнительные ссылки

Возможности Suricate далеко не ограничиваются описанным в данном ответе.

- [**Описание Suricate со скринкастами**](https://github.com/nsubiron/SublimeSuricate),
- [**Часть документации, касающаяся настройке запуска команд**](http://sublime-suricate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-guide/),
- [**Описание параметров настройки команд с примерами**](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nsubiron/SublimeSuricate/master/profiles/Default.suricate-profile).