# Sublime Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected trailing characters

Tags: sublime-text

> Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected trailing characters in C:\xxxx\ST2\Data\Package\User\Preferences.sublime-settings:xx:x

Пытаюсь сделать - 
"Вот несколько настроек подсмотренных в блоге у Wes Bos. Настройки прописываются в конфигурационном файле который открывается через меню Preferences -> Settings - User."

"fade_fold_buttons": false — показать кнопки сворачивания кода.

Comment: У меня некорректно работал Package Control, вылезла эта же ошибка. Разрешилась проблема заменой файла **Package Control.sublime-settings** на
 [оригинальный](https://github.com/wbond/package_control/blob/master/Package%20Control.sublime-settings). Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Настройки указываются в формате **JSON**.
**Вариант А: Вы забыли поставить запятую после предыдущего свойства.**

У после последнего элемента массива запятая не нужна, поэтому такая запись корректна:

```
{
    "font_size": 9
}
```

Не поставлена запятая перед добавленным свойством. **Это неверно:**

```
{
    "font_size": 9
    "fade_fold_buttons": false
}
```

**Правильно будет вот так:**

```
{
    "font_size": 9,
    "fade_fold_buttons": false
}
```

**Вариант Б: Файл был пуст, когда вы добавляли новое свойство.**
Оберните свойство в фигурные скобки

**Неверно:**

```
"fade_fold_buttons": false
```

**Верно:**

```
{
    "fade_fold_buttons": false
}
```

Comment: выдает ту же ошибку

Comment: Покажите содержимое файла настроек