# После установки emmet не работает shift+alt+стрелка

Tags: sublime-text, emmet

*Sublime text 3*. *Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.3*.

Emmet установлен штатно через *Package control*.

Очень нужная для меня функция ввода множественных курсоров по <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>стрелка</kbd> перестала работать. Не заместилась на другую, а просто ничего не происходит.

Пришлось пока отключить *Emmet* в настройках, а жаль.

Как разрешить конфликт?

Answer (score 3):

В примере рассмотрим, что делать, если больше не функционирует сочетание <kbd>Alt+Shift+↑</kbd>, хотя Emmet занимает и <kbd>Alt+Shift+↓</kbd>.

### Что делать, если перестали работать горячие клавиши

Либо вы хотите испробовать какое-то новое сочетание, но результата нет или он совсем не такой, какой по идее должен быть.

В нередко используемых и находящихся в автозагрузке программах я дезактивирую горячие клавиши, если не планирую ими пользоваться. Некоторые программы регистрируют шорткаты глобально, и есть шанс нарваться на конфликт горячих клавиш. Ну а нужные мне комбинации сохраняются в голове, при необходимости они вспоминаются.

Если убедились, что проблема не в стороннем софте, значит, скорее всего, она возникает из-за несогласованности сочетаний между плагинами в Sublime Text 3. Также они имеют нехорошее на мой взгляд свойство изменять дефолтные сочетания. Раз уж Emmet этим злоупотребляет, то что говорить о малоиспользуемых плагинах.

Ещё вариант — после обновлений Sublime Text до новых билдов, некоторые сочетания могут быть заменены/удалены разработчиками. Порядок действий, впрочем, остаётся тем же.

#### 1. Плохое решение

[Поудаляй плагины по одному — узнаешь в каком дело.](https://toster.ru/answer?answer_id=848611#answers_list_answer)
Это может быть долго, потребовать переустановки множества плагинов, вы не узнаете причин, вызвавших конфликт в проблемном плагине; и неясно, что делать, если нужны как плагин, так и занятый им шорткат.

#### 2. Не самое удачное решение

Проделывать **только**:

<kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Key Bindings - Default</kbd> (если перестали работать горячие клавиши по умолчанию)/ → <kbd>Package Settings</kbd> → <имя плагина, в котором начали отказывать хоткеи> → <kbd>Settings</kbd> - <kbd>Default</kbd> (когда перестали функционировать горячие клавиши в одном из плагинов) → поиском ищем отказавшее сочетание → копируем содержащую его строку → вставляем её в файл, открывающийся после <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → Key Bindings - <kbd>Default</kbd>. Для <kbd>Alt+Shift+↑</kbd> строка следующая:

> `{ "keys": ["alt+shift+up"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} },`

В этом файле с расширением `sublime-keymap` используется синтаксис JSON, если не знаете его, и у Вас будет выскакивать окно с ошибками, читаем [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/516668/199934) (ищем по тексту *JSON-синтаксис*) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/238934/199934).

Хоткей заработает, но вы не узнаете, в каком плагине и тем более, какой из его команд проблема.

#### 3. Хорошее решение

Плагин [Keymaps](https://github.com/MiroHibler/sublime-keymaps). После установки <kbd>Tools</kbd> → <kbd>Keymaps</kbd> → <kbd>Cheat Sheet</kbd>.

[image: Cheat Sheet]

Откроется полный список горячих клавиш Sublime Text 3: по умолчанию, занятых плагинами и пользовательских.

[image: Keymaps]

Находим поиском по открывшемуся файлу, какая команда какого плагина занимает наш шорткат, определяем, нужна она нам или нет, если нет, то проделываем действия, описанные в предыдущем разделе.

У метода есть один недостаток. У меня не работало сочетание <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> — выделение строки. В Cheat Sheat мне не удалось найти ничего, что занимало это сочетание. Оказалось, в одном из плагинов использовалось сочетание <kbd>Ctrl+K, Ctrl+L</kbd>, а хоткеем <kbd>Ctrl+L</kbd> вызывалась та же самая команда, что и <kbd>Ctrl+K, Ctrl+L</kbd>.

#### 4. Способ наверняка

<kbd>Ctrl+'</kbd> (машинописный обратный апостроф, символ расположен на той же клавише, где кириллическая «ё») → вводим в открывшееся поле `sublime.log_commands(True)`, затем `sublime.log_input(True)`.

- `sublime.log_input(True)` — встроенный в Sublime Text 3 кейлоггер, вывод осуществляется в ту же консоль, которую мы открыли сочетанием <kbd>Ctrl+`</kbd>.
- `sublime.log_commands(True)` — вывод лога команд в эту консоль.

Нажимаем в любом месте открытого файла проблемный хоткей, в примере это <kbd>Alt+Shift+↑</kbd>, смотрим вывод:

```
key evt: shift+alt+up
command: run_emmet_action {"action": "increment_number_by_10"}
```

По командам в Sublime Text 3 обычно становится ясным, что за плагин их использует, в данном случае Emmet. Для подробностей, что означает команда, можно погуглить или же пройтись по пути <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Package Settings</kbd> → <kbd>Emmet</kbd> → <kbd>Key Bindings - Default</kbd> . Для себя я решил: мне не нужно, чтобы Emmet занимал это сочетание, и проделал действия, описанные в разделе 2.

Раз в Emmet, установленном почти [2 миллиона раз](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emmet), таки решили перекрыть <kbd>Alt+Shift+↑</kbd>, обращение к его разработчикам, полагаю, имеет небольшие шансы на благоприятный исход. Для полной уверенности по моему мнению эффективнее уметь обращаться с горячими клавишами самостоятельно.