# В Sublime Text 3 не работает подсветка Babel скриптов, встроенных в HTML

Tags: reactjs, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, babel

[image: не подсвечивается код]

Код между тегами `<script></script>` не подсвечивается, когда я ставлю `type="text/babel"` т. к. использую ReactJS. Редактор — Sublime Text 3. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 3):

**UPD**

Мой feature request, созданный по мотивам данного вопроса, [**был закрыт**](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime/issues/291#issuecomment-263168143), улучшать синтаксис babel-скриптов в HTML разработчики пакета Babel не собираются. Кого ещё можно просить — без понятия.

Таким образом, именно для данного случая придётся или

- писать собственный синтаксис (что дело не одного часа),

или

- не встраивать инлайновые скрипты Babel в HTML,

или

- пользоваться альтернативами Sublime Text.

---

---

### 1. Предупреждение

Лучше **не встраивайте инлайновые скрипты**, не мучайтесь. На момент написания ответа разработка плагина [**Babel**](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime) — по сути, содержащего единственный специальный синтаксис для Babel, приостановлена, поддержка браузерного варианта Babel, встроенного в HTML, [**плохая, даже очень**](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime/issues/291).

Но можете и почитать данный ответ. Он больше полезен для других во многом аналогичных случаев.

[image: Babel]

---

---

### 2. Ограничения

- Дефолтный синтаксис `HTML.sublime-syntax` на момент написания данного ответа не поддерживает babel-скрипты. Неплохо было бы сделать [**feature request**](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues) разработчикам Sublime Text, не пакета Babel.
- В одном файле нельзя применять 2 или более синтаксисов (или я плохо гуглю). Один файл — один синтаксис.

---

---

### 3. Установка подсветки для babel-скриптов

Скачиваем через Package Control плагин [**Babel**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Babel) для работы с ReactJS, и [**Schemr**](https://github.com/benweier/Schemr) — для простого переключения по цветовым схемам.

Устанавливаем синтаксис `JavaScript (Babel)` для файлов с расширением `html`, как расписано [**здесь**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592517/199934).

#### 1. Выбор цветовой схемы

Теперь выбираем цветовую схему с поддержкой Babel-скриптов: можно установить [**дополнительные схемы**](https://github.com/babel/babel-sublime#suggested-resources), но для примера поставим Monokai Phoenix, встроенную в плагин Babel. <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> → `Schemr: List All Schemes` → выбираем `Monokai Phoenix [Dark]` → цветовая схема установлена.

---

---

### 4. Проблема 1: не желаю цветовую схему с поддержкой Babel для остальных файлов

Допустим, помимо EcmaScript Вы программируете на Python. Цветовые схемы для Babel плохо подсвечивают Python-скрипты, для Python лучше пользоваться схемой, поддерживающей Python.

В данном разделе описывается, как установить цветовую схему Monokai Phoenix только для файлов с расширением `html`, в остальных будет применяться Ваша цветовая схема по умолчанию.

Не делаем ничего из приведённого в п. 3.1, если сделали — откатитесь. Далее, как [**расписано в книге «Sublime Text Power User»**](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/Kristinita/SashaBooks/blob/master/IT/Sublime%20Text/Sublime%20Text%20Power%20User.pdf#page=73), `Preferences` → `Browse Packages` → `User` → создаём файл `HTML.sublime-settings` → между {фигурными скобками} вставляем следующий код:

```json
"color_scheme": "Packages/Babel/Monokai Phoenix.tmTheme",
```

Не путайтесь в [**JSON-синтаксисе**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/238934/199934), следите за правильной расстановкой кавычек, скобок и запятых. Например, мой файл `HTML.sublime-settings` выглядит так:

```json
{
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Babel/Monokai Phoenix.tmTheme",
    "enable_table_editor": true,
    "extensions":
    [
    ]
}
```

Сохраняем файл → для файлов с расширением `html` будет применяться цветовая схема Monokai Phoenix, для остальных — Ваша по умолчанию.

---

---

### 5. Как определить путь к файлу цветовой схемы

Процесс во многом аналогичен определению пути к файлу синтаксиса — [**см. раздел 3 данного ответа**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592517/199934).

#### 1. Через встроенную консоль

Открываем файл, для которого применяется схема Monokai Phoenix → <kbd>Ctrl+'</kbd> (машинописный обратный апостроф, символ расположен на той же клавише, где кириллическая «ё») → вставляем в открывшуюся консоль следующий код:

```python
print(view.settings().get("color_scheme"))
```

На выходе должны получить

```
'Packages/Babel/Monokai Phoenix.tmTheme'.
```

Результат (без 'кавычек') вставляем как значение параметра `color_scheme` из предыдущего раздела.

#### 2. При помощи PackageResourceViewer

Устанавливаем плагин [**PackageResourceViewer**](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer) → `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` →

- `ColorSheme - Default`, если пользуетесь одной из цветовых тем по умолчанию,
- `$Название Вашего плагина` — если пользуетесь цветовой схемой, установленной в каком-либо из плагинов,

В нашем случае набираем `Babel` → ищем в выпадающем меню файл с расширением `tmTheme` → в рассматриваемом случае это `Monokai Phoenix.tmTheme`. `Packages/$Название плагина/$имя файла цветовой схемы.tmTheme` и нужно вставлять напротив параметра `color_scheme` в файле `HTML.sublime-settings`.

---

---

### 6. Проблема 2: Желательно, чтобы синтаксис `Javascript (Babel)` был только в html-файлах с Babel-скриптами

Применять синтаксис `JavaScript (Babel)` для HTML-файлов, не содержащих Babel-скрипты нежелательно, поскольку:

- В нём не так детально расписаны правила для HTML, CSS и JavaScript, как в дефолтном синтаксисе HTML.
- Цветовые схемы для Babel недостаточно поддерживают HTML, CSS и JavaScript, как схемы, специализирующиеся на HTML, CSS и JavaScript.

#### 1. Настройка

В данном подразделе расписано, как настроить следующее:

- Когда в html-файлах отсутствуют babel-скрипты, применяется синтаксис для HTML по умолчанию.
- Присутствуют — автоматически определяется `JavaScript (Babel)` синтаксис.

Если проделывали действия из пп. 3.1 и 4, откатите их.

Проделайте действия из пункта 3.1 с одним исключением — файл будет называться не `HTML.sublime-settings`, а `JavaScript (Babel).sublime-settings`, где `JavaScript (Babel)` — имя файла синтаксиса (как узнать имя, см. [**здесь в разделе 3**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592517/199934)).

Устанавливаем через Package Control плагин [**ApplySyntax**](https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax) → `Preferences` → `Package Settings` → `ApplySyntax` → `Settings - User` → увидите правило `"syntaxes": []`. В нём между [квадратными скобками] добавляем следующий код и сохраняем файл:

```json
{
    "match": "all",
    "rules":
    [
        {
            "file_path": ".*\\.html$"
        },
        {
            "contains": "<script [^>]*type=\"text\\/babel\"[^>]*>"
        }
    ],
    "syntax": "Babel/JavaScript (Babel)"
}
```

После сохранения синтаксис файла, содержащего атрибут `type="text/babel"` в теге `script` должен измениться на `Babel/JavaScript (Babel)`. Если удалите `type="text/babel"` из файла и сохраните его → смены синтаксиса обратно не произойдёт, но после того, как Вы закроете его и откроете снова, вернётся подсветка от синтаксиса HTML.

#### 2. Параметры

- `syntax` — путь к файлу синтаксиса. Как его получить, читаем [**здесь в разделе 3**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592517/199934).
- `file_path` — что должно содержаться в имени файла, дабы к нему применялся синтаксис из параметра `syntax`. Обратите внимание:

  - Значением параметра является не расширение, а регулярное выражение; `.*\\.html$` означает, что синтаксис будет применяться к любым файлам, содержащим `.html` на конце.
  - Необходимо экранировать экранирующие слэши, поэтому идут 2 слэша подряд.
- `contains` — какая строка должна содержаться в файле, чтобы к нему применялся синтаксис. В значении регулярное выражение, в нашем случае означающее, что тег `<script>` должен содержать атрибут `type="text/babel"`.
- `"match": "all"`, — параметр, указывающий, что будет применён параметр rules и проигнорирован параметр extensions — см. [**пункт 2**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592517/199934). Не рекомендуется его опускать: если в файле с синтаксисом для ReactJS Вы убрали строку, содержащуюся в `contains` и захотели вновь установить дефолтный синтаксис HTML, при отсутствии параметра `match` Sublime Text не даст Вам этого сделать, возвращая синтаксис `JavaScript (Babel)`.

Если ограничения строкой недостаточно, существуют другие варианты, описанные в [**документации**](http://facelessuser.github.io/ApplySyntax/usage/):

- [**`first_line`**](http://facelessuser.github.io/ApplySyntax/usage/#first-line-rule) — автоопределение синтаксиса, исходя из первой строки файла.
- [**`interpreter`**](http://facelessuser.github.io/ApplySyntax/usage/#interpreter-shebang) — упрощение `first_line` для языков программирования, в которых используется [**шебанг**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix)). Если в первой строке файла есть шебанг и слово `python`, то вместо `{"first_line": "^#\\!(?:.+)python"}` достаточно написать `{"interpreter": "python"}`. Пример. Допустим, хочу, чтобы выражение, содержащее в начале `#!/usr/bin/env python -c`, подсвечивалось бы заранее установленным синтаксисом [**PythonImproved**](https://github.com/MattDMo/PythonImproved), а не дефолтным Python. Часть моего файла `ApplySyntax.sublime-settings`:

```json
    {
        "match": "all",
        "rules": [{
            "interpreter": "python",
        }, ],
        "syntax": "Python Improved/PythonImproved"
    }
```

[image: Шебанг]

- [**`function_rule`**](http://facelessuser.github.io/ApplySyntax/usage/#function-rule) — в более сложных случаях можно определить синтаксис для файла, если в нём содержится определённая функция. Когда будете использовать данный параметр, обратите внимание на настройку [**reraise_exeptions**](http://facelessuser.github.io/ApplySyntax/usage/#re-raise-exceptions).

---

---

### 7. Правка файла синтаксиса

Можно включить подсветку синтаксиса для Babel-скриптов в файле `HTML.sublime-syntax` или каком-либо другом самостоятельно по образцу, расписанному в [**данном ответе**](https://toster.ru/q/338308#answer_852790) для Gulp. Но есть проблемы:

- Нужно выделить свободное время и иметь также навыки и опыт работы с синтаксисами Sublime Text,
- Если Вы правите дефолтные файлы синтаксисов Sublime Text или файлы синтаксисов из плагинов, будьте готовы к тому, что после обновлений Ваши изменения пропадут. Поэтому позаботьтесь о сохранении копий файлов, чтобы потом мержить из них в обновлённые файлы.
- Можно обойти проблему обновлений, скопировав содержимое файла синтаксиса в свой файл, путь к которому и будет значением параметра `syntax` в файле `User/ApplySyntax.sublime-settings`. Но тогда Вашего файла не коснутся обновления от разработчиков Sublime Text/плагинов для него.

---

---

### 8. Дополнительные ссылки

- [**Документация плагина ApplySyntax**](http://facelessuser.github.io/ApplySyntax/usage/),
- [**Настройка автоматического определения синтаксиса для расширений файлов в Sublime Text**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592517/199934),
- [**Как задать синтаксис для новой вкладки в Sublime Text?**](https://toster.ru/q/335977#answer_850379)
- [**Как в Sublime Text 3 добавить свой цвет элементу, отсутствующему в синтаксисе?**](https://toster.ru/q/338308#answer_852790)

Answer (score 0):

1. Поставить плагин для подсветки jsx кода.
2. Внизу справа в саблайме выбрать тип кода `javascript(babel)` или просто `babel`.

Comment: @Arhad все равно не весь код подсвечивает.

Comment: @Nick, автор сообщения – Alex Slobodyansky. Я всего лишь внёс стилистическую правку.