# Настройка автоматического определения синтаксиса для расширений файлов в Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3

Не помню точно, что тогда сделал, но теперь при открытии `css` или `less` файлов автоматически ставится синтаксис Pascal. Не знаете, как это убрать?
Редактор — Sublime Text 3.

[image: screen]

Comment: [**Пункт 2**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/513322/199934) ответа посмотрите или плагином [**Apply Syntax**](https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax) воспользуйтесь. Спасибо.

Comment: первый способ помог, спасибо

Comment: Если нужно просто установить нужный синтаксис, первого способа достаточно, однако плагин добавляет множество возможностей, описанных в [**документации**](http://facelessuser.github.io/ApplySyntax/usage/). Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Положим, у нас установлен плагин `LESS`, но при открытии файлов с расширением `less` синтаксис определяется как `Pascal`.

---

---

### 1. Без установки дополнительных плагинов

`View` → `Syntax` → `Open all with current extension as...` → `LESS` → отныне ко всем файлам с расширением `less` будет автоматически применяться синтаксис `LESS`.

---

---

### 2. ApplySyntax

Многофункциональный плагин для работы с автоматическим определением синтаксисов. О прочих его возможностях я рассказал в других ответах.

Устанавливаем [**плагин**](https://github.com/facelessuser/ApplySyntax) через Package Control → `Preferences` → `Package Settings` → `ApplySyntax` → `Settings - User` → увидите правило `"syntaxes": []`. В нём между [квадратными скобками] добавляем следующий код:

```json
{
    "extensions":
    [
        "less"
    ],
    "syntax": "LESS/LESS"
},
```

Не путайтесь в [**JSON-синтаксисе**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/238934/199934), следите за правильной расстановкой кавычек, скобок и запятых.

- `extensions` — расширение, которому мы настраиваем синтаксис,

> ```
>   Обратите внимание, что перед расширением не ставится точка, 
>   как во многих аналогичных случаях. Точка нужна, если Вы хотите
>   настроить синтаксис файлам, у которых точка — часть имени, а не
>   расширение, например, .gitignore.
> ```

- `syntax` — относительный путь к файлу синтаксиса после Packages и без расширения.

---

---

### 3. Как определить путь к файлу синтаксиса

Обычно достаточно повторения компьютерного языка через слэш — `Python/Python` или `PHP/PHP`, — но иногда это не срабатывает.

#### 1. Через встроенную консоль

Открываем файл, в котором нормально определён синтаксис `LESS` → <kbd>Ctrl+'</kbd> (машинописный обратный апостроф, символ расположен на той же клавише, где кириллическая «ё») → вставляем в открывшуюся консоль следующий код:

```python
view.settings().get('syntax')
```

На выходе должны получить

```
'Packages/LESS/LESS.tmLanguage'.
```

#### 2. При помощи PackageResourceViewer

Но что, если нет возможности открыть файл, где необходимый синтаксис успешно применяется? Устанавливаем плагин [**PackageResourceViewer**](https://github.com/skuroda/PackageResourceViewer), `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` → вводим название нашего компьютерного языка/средства программирования — если пользуетесь одним из дефолтных синтаксисов — или плагина — когда нужен синтаксис, внедрённый в плагин. В нашем случае набираем `LESS` → ищем в выпадающем меню файл с расширением `tmLanguage` (старый формат синтаксиса в Sublime Text) или `sublime-syntax` ([**новый формат**](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html)) → в рассматриваемом случае это `LESS.tmLanguage`. `$Название плагина/$имя файла синтаксиса без расширения` и нужно вставлять напротив параметра `syntax` в ApplySyntax.

---

---

### 4. Дополнительные ссылки

- [**Документация плагина ApplySyntax**](http://facelessuser.github.io/ApplySyntax/usage/),
- [**Как задать автоопределение синтаксиса для новой вкладки**](https://toster.ru/q/335977?e=4590642#answer_item_850379),
- [**В Sublime Text 3 не работает подсветка Babel скриптов, встроенных в HTML**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592776/199934).