# В Sublime Text 3 не работает emmet

Tags: html, sublime-text-3, emmet

Структура html не появляется после нажатия **! + tab.** Также не работает **ul>li*5**.
Переустановка не помогает.

https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/issues/478 данные инструкции тоже не помогли решить проблему.

Comment: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/issues/406

Comment: В консоли (за `Ctrl`+`~`) есть какая-нибудь ругань по поводу Emmet? (После установки из PackageControl, при попытке развернуть аббревиатуру, ещё в какой-нибудь момент...)

Comment: @D-side Нет никаких ошибок.

Comment: То есть, он нормально скачал PyV8 и смог запуститься? Значит, по всей видимости, проблема не в Emmet, а в том, что кто-то стянул его хоткей себе и не отдаёт.

Comment: @D-side Да, все корректно установилось. Сейчас проверю на ключи.

Comment: @D-side    `"keys": [
            "tab"
        ], 
        "command": "expand_abbreviation_by_tab", 
        "context": [ 
            {
                "operand": "source.css, source.sass, source.less, source.scss, source.stylus, source.postcss, source.jade, text.jade, text.slim, text.xml, text.html- source, text.haml, text.scala.html, source string", 
                "operator": "equal", 
                "match_all": true, 
                "key": "selector"`

Comment: То что этот конфиг есть, не означает, что он нигде не оверрайдится :\

Answer (score 2):

у меня тоже ни с того, ни с сего перестало работать развертывание. помог совет Прогера, ревключить синтаксис HTML
На верхней панели инструментов ST ищем View, потом Syntax -> HTML, кликаем и проверяем. и переназначать ничего не надо было

Comment: А Прогер это кто?

Comment: да сверху ответчик. сори, не знал что незареганные так все так именуются)

Answer (score 1):

Preferences -> Settings.
Проверьте что в ignored_packages нет Emmet и других плагинов

Comment: Помогло закомментровал:
`"ignored_packages":
 [
  /*"Vintage"*/
 ]`

Answer (score 1):

Помогла переустановка emmet-а с последующим перезапуском Sublime Text

Comment: Автору вопроса переустановка не помогла.

Answer (score 1):

мне помогло удаление плагина colorPicker

Answer (score 1):

У меня перестал работать плагин emmet.
Нажатие кнопки TAB после знака ! = отступ, ul>li*5 = отступ.
При этом в CSS все работает норм.

Проблему решил так: Package Settings > Emmet > Key bindings - user

строки 125, 126 - заменил "tab" на "alt+x"

```
{ "keys": ["alt+x"], "command": "insert_best_completion", "args": {"default": "\t", "exact": true} },
{ "keys": ["alt+x"], "command": "insert_best_completion", "args": {"default": "\t", "exact": false},
```

Comment: Всё заработало благодаря способу @Viktor Mashkov: >Package Settings > Emmet > Key bindings - user
>строки 125, 126 - заменил "tab" на "alt+x" ```
{ "keys": ["alt+x"], "command": "insert_best_completion", "args": {"default": "\t", "exact": true} },
{ "keys": ["alt+x"], "command": "insert_best_completion", "args": {"default": "\t", "exact": false},
``` Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Помогло переназначение хоткеев **tab** в *emmet* > *KeyBindings* > *User*.

Comment: Вариант. Но интересно, кто стянул его у Emmet. Добавьте в вопрос список ваших пакетов или изучите сами, удаляя пакеты по одному.

Answer (score 0):

У меня не работал Emmet, много что перепробовал, ничего не помогало.
Вот что я сделал чтобы проблема ушла! Сначала создаем новый документ Сtrl+N, затем Ctrl+S сохраняем указывая имя файла Index.html (важность играет именно приписка .html, а не само название), после чего сохраняем. Вуаля.

Answer (score 0):

В настройках надо отключить включить HTML-синтаксис и будет вам счастье

Comment: Если свет выключить и включить, он как горел, так и будет гореть. Что будет в случае вашего решения?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно поменять синтаксис:
View --> Syntax --> HTML

Comment: Синтаксис [**так**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592517/199934) правильно менять. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Помог этот способ:

Сначала создаем новый документ <kbd>Сtrl+N</kbd>, затем <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> сохраняем указывая имя файла `Index.html` (важность играет именно приписка `.html`, а не само название), после чего сохраняем.

Answer (score 0):

Зайди в Preferences > Packagec Sittings
Там удали Emmet и установи обратно.
мне помогло

Comment: по сути ничем не отличается от одного из других ответов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/851643/178576

Answer (score 0):

Внимение! Если у вас вдруг перестал работать Ememt в SublimeText, именно в HTML файле. То проблема заключается в том, что скорее всего где-то в коде у вас Emoji символы или другие Unicode символы. Как только вы их удалите, emmet сразу заработает. И не нужно ничего переключать и т.д.

Answer (score -1):

Если ничего из вышеуказанного не помогает, просто снимите галочку с **view > word** **wrap**