# Sublime Text 3 plugin Emmet "!+tab" вместо <!doctype5 html> ... "!important"

Tags: sublime-text-3, emmet

Всем доброго времени суток!
У меня в Sublime Text 3 установлен plugin Emmet, через Package Control, и при использовании комбинации `"!+tab"` (у меня "ctrl+1" через Key Bindings)

```
"keys": ["ctrl+1"],
    "args":
    {
        "action": "expand_abbreviation"
    },
    "command": "run_emmet_action",
    "context": [
    {
        "key": "emmet_action_enabled.expand_abbreviation"
    }]
```

При открытии нового пустого файла с расширением .html (у меня отключены все плагины html в Package Control) переключаюсь на emmet и вместо `<!DOCTYPE html>
 ...`

выводиться `!important`. Ввожу `"!+tab"` (в первой строке нового файла с расширением .html).

Работает способ `"html:5 + tab"`но это долго.

Помогите пожалуйста исправить так чтобы при `"!+tab"` emmet работал с html snippetами и выводил `<!DOCTYPE html>
 ...`

Мой log Sublime Text 3

```
key evt: control+1 (у вас это "tab")
command: run_emmet_action {"action": "expand_abbreviation"}
```

UPD: Алгоритм создания нового файла.

Я создаю новый пустой файл в рабочей папке, называю его и добавляю расширение .html. Затем открываю его с помощью Sublime Text 3. В консоле Sublime Text 3:

```
>>> view.settings().get('syntax')
'Packages/Text/Plain text.tmLanguage'
```

UPD2: 
Preferences → Browse packages... → User → Default(Linux).[sublime-keymap](https://www.pastery.net/kaxsbp/#kaxsbp)
Troubleshooting: [Generate Bug Report Template](http://%20https://www.pastery.net/exjkzu/)

Comment: **1.** На всякий случай, желаемое для Вас автодополнение будет работать для HTML-синтаксисов. Для других (CSS, SASS и т. п.) будет иным. **2.** Вы открываете пустой HTML или что-то другое? Дополните вопрос, где именно Вы вводите `! + Tab`. **3.** Если HTML, добавьте в вопрос Ваш синтаксис. Как его получить, см. [**здесь**](https://kristinita.ru/IT-articles/How-to-get-current-%E2%80%A6-in-Sublime-Text#method-1),

Comment: **4.** Если синтаксис HTML, а по-прежнему не работает, введите в консоль Sublime Text `sublime.log_commands(True)` и `sublime.log_input(True)` → оставьте консоль открытой → добавьте в вопрос то, что там выводится после того, как Вы нажали `! + Tab`. Спасибо.

Comment: @Саша Черных обновил информацию по Вашим комментариям

Comment: discipleartem, дополните вопрос следующей информацией: **1.** `При открытии нового пустого файла с расширением .html` — подробнее распишите, пожалуйста, как это делаете. **а)** Вы создаёте пустой файл с расширением `.html`, а затем открываете его, **б)** Вы создаёте новый буфер обмена (`File` → `New File`), **в)** что-то другое. **2.** Как бы Вы не открывали файл, перед тем, как что-то туда вводить, пожалуйста, [**получите его синтаксис**](https://kristinita.ru/IT-articles/How-to-get-current-%E2%80%A6-in-Sublime-Text#syntax) и добавьте эту информацию в вопрос. Спасибо.

Comment: @Саша Черных upd

Comment: **1.** У Вас синтаксис Plain Text, а нужно HTML. Как его установить для файлов HTML, см. [**сюда**](https://toster.ru/q/335977?e=4590642#answer_item_850379). После установки синтаксиса попробуйте воспроизвести проблему в новом синтаксисе. **2.** `у меня отключены все плагины html в Package Control` — возможно, Вы отключили синтаксис HTML. Чтобы проверить это, `Ctrl + Shift + P` → `Package Control: Enable Package` → если там в списке есть `HTML`, выберите его.

Comment: **3.** Возможно, Вы редактировали `Default` keymap, тогда как надо `User`, и что-то поломалось. `Preferences` → `Package Settings` → `Emmet` → собственные хоткеи всегда нужно задавать в `Key Bindings - User`. Если что-то изменяли в `Key Bindings - Default`, верните значения по умолчанию [**отсюда**](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime) из файла `Default (<Ваша ОС>).sublime-keymap`.

Comment: @ Саша Черных Да Вы были правы - не нужно было отключать стандартный пакет(синтаксис) HTML в  Sublime Text 3. Оформите ответ основываясь на ваших комментариях и я одобрю его.

Comment: @Саша Черных но это работал синтаксис HTML  а когда я переключаюсь на emmet то по прежнему "!important"

Comment: @Саша Черных 3. Нет у меня параметры Default и Key Bindings - Default в Emmet не доступны для редактирования (не изменяются и не сохраняются).

Comment: discipleartem, **1.** Например, на [**Pastery**](https://www.pastery.net/) или другой Pastebin-сервис выложите содержимое своего файла `Preferences` → `Browse packages...` → `User` → `Default (Ваша ОС).sublime-keymap`. Затем скиньте сюда ссылку. Если есть файл `Default.sublime-keymap`, то же самое сделайте, пожалуйста. // **2.** Также установите пакет [**Troubleshooting**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Troubleshooting) → `Ctrl + Shift + P` → `Troubleshooting: Generate Bug Report Template` → тоже выложите на pastebin-сервис, что получилось, и скиньте ссылку.

Comment: @СашаЧерных добавил ссылки

Comment: discipleartem, **Статус: Проблема воспроизведена**. Согласно [**этой строке**](https://www.pastery.net/exjkzu/#l-32-exjkzu) отчёта у Вас в HTML-файлах используется синтаксис `Emmet`. я попробовал — да, получается `!important`. А нужен синтаксис для HTML: `HTML` или `HTML5`. Как это настроить, см. [**здесь**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592517/199934). Спасибо.

Comment: discipleartem, не нужно настраивать для файлов синтаксис `Emmet`. Пакет Emmet сам автоматически подберёт, какие автодополнения использовать в HTML, какие в CSS, SASS и т. д. Спасибо.

Comment: @Саша Черных да, спасибо. С html синтаксисом все работает.