# Перестала работать комбинация клавиш Sublime Text 3 (hotkey) focus_group {"group": 1}

Tags: sublime-text-3, hotkeys

Перестала работать "комбинация клавиш" в Sublime Text 3.

У меня установлен пакет SublimeREPL и сделан "Key Bindings" (user)

```
[
{

    "keys": ["ctrl+2"],
    "command": "repl_open",
    "args":
    {
        "cmd": ["../venv/bin/python", "-u", "$file_basename"],
        "cwd": "$file_path",
        "encoding": "utf8",
        "extend_env":
        {
            "PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8"
        },
        "external_id": "python",
        "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
        "type": "subprocess"
    },

    "keys": ["ctrl+1"],
    "args":
    {
        "action": "expand_abbreviation"
    },
    "command": "run_emmet_action",
    "context": [
    {
        "key": "emmet_action_enabled.expand_abbreviation"
    }]
}, ]
```

Вывод консоли Sublime Text 3 sublime.log_commands(True)

```
command: focus_group {"group": 1}
```

форматирование может быть неправильным так как я использую пакет HTML-CSS-JS Prettify. Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50577326/sublime-text-subl-open-file-in-specific-group-from-command-line/50577526#50577526) может быть подсказка (в которой я не разобрался).

Comment: **1.** У Вас ошибка в файле, каждый блок `key` — `command` необходимо оборачивать в {фигурные скобки}. Правильно [**так**](https://www.pastery.net/zukjng/). Будьте внимательны. // **2.** Установите [**PackageDev**](https://github.com/SublimeText/PackageDev) для улучшенной подсветки синтаксиса кеймапа.

Comment: // **3.** Крайне не рекомендую использовать для своих шорткатов распространённые сочетания клавиш, так как возникают конфликты. Советую пользоваться Command Palette, а если команда нужна часто, то использовать сочетания, чтобы была меньше вероятность конфликта хоткеев. В своих персональных шорткатах я использую клавишу Super(Win), которую редко задействуют. // **4.** Посмотреть, какие хоткеи уже задействованы, можно при помощи пакета [**Sublime Keymaps**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Keymaps). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Спасибо, мне помогло. Что делать с вопросом ?

Comment: discipleartem, не удаляйте. [**Эта проблема**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/874008/199934) решилась с корректным кеймапом? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных нет, при синтаксисе emmet "! + cntrl+1" по прежнему выдает "!important" вместо <doctype> .....