# Форматирование php в Sublime text 3

Tags: php, sublime-text, sublime-text-3, format

Я установил

- https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PHP%20Codebeautifier
- https://packagecontrol.io/packages/phpfmt
- https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CodeFormatter

Я установил php php-7.1.0-Win32-VC14-x64 из https://secure.php.net/downloads.php в "C:\Program Files\php"

Указал в настройках phpfmt и CodeFormatter `"C:/Program Files/php/php.exe"`. Запускаю их команды форматирования через `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`. И ничего. Никаких ошибок, никаких действий. Я не подозреваю куда смотреть и куда писать.

Меня интересует форматирование php файлов смешанных с html.

Вот из такого:

```
<?
    if (true)
{
                echo 'me';
    }
?>
<?
if (false): ?>
    <div>           <h1>Normal</h1>
    </div>
<?endif;    ?>
```

Надо такой:

```
<?
    if (true) {
        echo 'me';
    }
?>
<? if (false) { ?>
    <div>
        <h1>Normal</h1>
    </div>
<? } ?>
```

Я умею пользоваться регулярками, поэтому, если будет только в один иф переформатировать, то не беда. Лишь бы не умирал, когда встретит `?>`.

Comment: @higimo, пример файла, который необходимо отформатировать, можете привести? Можно в самом вопросе. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных спасибо, что сказали — добавил.

Comment: Ctrl+` открывает консоль Sublime, оттуда можно что-то узнать

Comment: higimo, смотрите, думаю, удовлетворит Вас такое решение. я тестировал различные онлайн-форматтеры — они хорошо форматируют либо только PHP или только HTML. Так, чтобы оба синтаксиса, — нашёл лишь [**такой**](http://www.cleancss.com/php-beautify/) и [**такой**](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html) форматтеры, но у них нет API.

Comment: Но можно разрешить проблему так: сначала отформатировать код как PHP, затем как HTML (или наоборот). Проверьте на своих реальных файлах, должно тоже работать помочь. В настройки CodeFormatter после установки вообще не нужно ничего прописывать, он сразу должен работать. [**Демонстрация для CodeFormatter**](http://i.imgur.com/zys1dNS.gif).

Comment: Чтобы запустить 2 команды как одну, нужен, например, (есть и другие способы) плагин [**Improved Macros**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ImprovedMacros). После установки его и пакета [**Suricate**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Suricate) [**добавляете в свой User/Default.suricate-profile**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/587973/199934) файл [**эти строки**](https://www.pastery.net/mvxanc/) (задержки в 3000 мс для демонстрации, можете убрать их). Должно получиться, как на демо.

Comment: Если Вас не устраивает дефолтное форматирование CodeFormatter, этот плагин настраиваемый, можете кастомизировать параметры под себя. // Спасибо.

Comment: @Naumov, в Sublime Text всё, что Вы сказали, есть, и об этом очень подробно рассказывается в книге [**Mastering Sublime Text**](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781849698429.do) Дэна Пелега. Возможно, специализированная под PHP IDE и имеет больше возможностей, но и в Sublime Text c PHP можно работать вполне. А точка зрения, что Sublime Text это «всего лишь текстовый редактор» уже достаточно давно не имеет под собой оснований. Спасибо.

Comment: @xEdelweiss, у меня на Windows 10 EN 64-bit воспроизводится проблема higimo для первых двух пакетов, притом в консоли ничего не выводится (притом что установлен [**Logging Control**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Logging%20Control) для дополнительного логирования. Хотя да, higimo лучше было бы сообщить об отсутствии output в вопросе. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных Я и неспорю, только не пойму зачем такие телодвижения когда всё равно перейдёте на sublime простой пример у вас в классе есть магические методы, и есть php dock описывающий класс, а также класс вы получаете с помощью getera.

Comment: @Naumov, `> когда всё равно перейдёте на sublime` — правильно :) .